# Change number of decimals in Woocommerce cart, checkout and my account

Tags: php, woocommerce, decimal, cart, account

Would it be possible to have a php code to insert in my child theme capable of passing my site to two decimal places after the comma for all the basket information subtotal total VAT Shipping the same for the checkout but also in the customer area

I would like to keep only the product to three decimal after the decimal point but the total rounded up to two decimal after the decimal point

can you help me

I am using *[Change number of decimals in Woocommerce cart totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550127/change-number-of-decimals-in-woocommerce-cart-totals/49551246#49551246)* answer code, for the cart and the checkout pages. It works perfectly but I am missing an info for it to work in the my order account tab.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsFRS.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change number of decimals in Woocommerce cart totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550127/change-number-of-decimals-in-woocommerce-cart-totals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my account section use [the conditional tag `is_account_page()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-10), so in the code:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals', 'change_prices_decimals', 20, 1 );
function change_prices_decimals( $decimals ){
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page() )
        $decimals = 2;
    return $decimals;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Related: [Change number of decimals in Woocommerce cart totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550127/change-number-of-decimals-in-woocommerce-cart-totals/49551246#49551246)

Comment: Hello ,

and yes Thank you it works perfectly it's this little piece of code that I was missing is_account_page ()) I still have to find the solution for the invoice the plugin which manages this and woocommerce-pdf-invoice

but thank you very much that solved a huge part of my problem bravo